# Trigger and control inside DetailView

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a DetailsView control with a LinkButton inside the TemplateField.

I wrap the DetailsView inside the UpdatePanel and set trigger with the LinkButton inside the DetailsView . However, i got error saying it can't find the LinkButton. I tried to google on setting trigger that is inside DetailsView and GridView but I haven't come across any post regarding how to do it.

Does anyone know how you can use the LinkButton inside it or DetailsView as trigger?

Comment: Can you put the code here as well?

Answer (score 1):

i find my answer. Basically set ChildrenAsTriggers to true in updatepanel. Any control inside the update panel will trigger it.